# App Invites for Android: How to set received message content

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-app-invites

I'm trying to test the new Google Play Services api "[App Invites for Android](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/)" that is currently in Beta. Maybe I'm missing something but after tried the sample app, reading the documentation, and tested it in my app I cannot figure out how to set the content message that will receive the invited person.

I just want to show some content with the app link in the play store like shows  the picture in documentation but all that I get is a simple text that says "Install this application".

[image]
[image]

Can someone that tested this new api help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add it to your own app it shows the play store content automatically.

Comment: Oh! ok, thanks. So, I guess is not showing it because I haven't uploaded yet to the PlayStore.

Comment: So for a published app, the message will show inside the email content and above the Play Store widget? And the title where it shows "Food2you App" is also added automatically for published apps?

Comment: I also wonder how one can customise the wording so that it doesn't show "Install this application" but rather "Hi Debbie, check out the Food2you App."

Comment: In the manual you have a possibility to change the wording while building the intent. 

here is the link: https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app

hope it helps

But a user can change that when composing an invite.

Answer (score 0):

```
            String inviteTitle = "This app is terrific. try and get $5 off ";
            String inviteMessage = "install the application";


            Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(inviteTitle)
                    .setMessage(inviteMessage)
                    .build();
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
```

Fairly certain its something like this